# Enable intellisense for imported tlb in VC++ 6

Tags: visual-c++, intellisense

We have a library for a complex COM object that we are importing using the following:

```
#import "library.tlb"
```

this works fine, VC++ compiles a tli file and somehow that gets magically included in the build process, so code written against the tlb works.

However, intellisense doesn't pick up the library entries.  This is a crazy complex COM component, and having intellisense would help immensely.  Can anyone provide some pointers on how to get intellisense to work properly with this?

I have tried deleting the .ncb file, and that had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

The commercial (not free) addin [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/) may be worth looking at.  It works in VC6.